# Using Inspect module to execute specific code

Tags: python, bytecode

For simplicity I have narrowed down my problem to the following:

I have a main function that executes a series of functions. From the first function `manipulate()`, I want to be able to prevent `test()` from exiting the program with `sys.exit()`. I also need to be able to silence `print("Silence me")` meaning that this should not show up in the output of my program. Lastly, my program still needs to be able to output `print("You need to hear this")` from the `test()` function.

```
def main():
    manipulate()
    test()
```

```
def manipulate():

    print("Silence me")
    sys.exit()
    print("You need to hear this")
```

How can I achieve this if I can only change the code in the manipulate() function?

I've tried looking into using the inspect module, but I think I may be missing something. I'm not sure if parsing the code for `test()` and running the parsed code through `exec()` is the proper way to do approach this.

```
def manipulate():
    def filter_exc(func):
        src = inspect.getsource(func)

        lines = src.split('\n')
        out = lines[0] + "\n"

        for line in lines[1:]:
            m = re.match('(\s*)(.*)', line)
            lead, text = m.groups()
            if 'sys.exit()' in line:
                continue
            if 'Silence Me' in line:
                continue
            out += "    " + text + '\n'

        return out

    exec(filter_exc(game_on))
```

Comment: If you want to do testing and change the behaviour of the dependencies, use the `unittest.mock` module.

Comment: Very strange assignment, did you make it up for yourself or someone gives this as homework?

Answer (score 0):

In this simple example I would just "monkeypatch" affected functionality:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

def test():
    print("Silence me")
    sys.exit()
    print("You need to hear this")

@contextmanager
def manipulate():
    global print

    try:
        _sys_exit_backup, sys.exit = sys.exit, lambda: None
        i = iter([lambda *args:None, print])
        _print_backup, print = print, lambda *args: next(i)(*args)
        yield
    finally:
        sys.exit = _sys_exit_backup
        print = _print_backup

def main():
    with manipulate():
        test()

main()
```

Prints:

```
You need to hear this
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that what you’re doing is bad. Programming languages designed do execute source code, not to limit the execution. Editing live bytecode is evil and will produce undebuggable errors.

Disclaimer aside, you can achieve this effect more cleanly by using [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) from standard lib to replace standard implementations of `exit` and `print`, but you need to execute something like

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import sys


def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
    # do whatever
    return


def my_exit(*args, **kwargs):
    # do whatever
    return


def perform_patch():
    patchers = [
        patch('__main__.print', my_print),
        patch('sys.exit', my_exit)
    ]
    for patcher in patchers:
        patcher.start()
    return patchers


def perform_unpatch(patchers):
    for patcher in patchers:
        patcher.stop()


def manipulate():
    print("hello")
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    patchers = perform_patch()
    manipulate() 
    perform_unpatch(patchers)
    print("I'm done!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Script outputs only "I'm done!".

`exit` and `print` remain patched until you call `patcher.stop()`. `patch` can be used in a `with` block, so it could be done cleaner if you can put `manipulate()` call inside the `with` statement.

Another way is to get the source code and use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to dynamically rewrite it. Here's a [talk about ASTs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhWvz4dK4ng).

Finally you could do something with a bytecode directly, here's a [talk exploring that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxjv9KqzwjI).

In the end I seriously encourage you to use any other possible way to edit the sources. If it's a library, then you'd be much better if you just fork it and edit the sources directly.